# Vertically align text next to an input inside <td>?

Tags: html, css, html-table, multiple-columns

I have a HTML as this:

```
<fieldset><legend>Callout Report</legend>
<table>
<tr><td>Start Time</td><td>
<input type="text" id="startTimeUI" autocomplete="off" />
</td></tr>

<tr><td>Callout&nbsp;ID</td><td>
<input type="text" id="id" name="id" size="10" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" />
<span class="calloutTitle">This can be a longer text which takes more than just one single line.</span>
</td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Output is like this:

[image]

But I want an output like this:

[image]

Of course, I could put a `<table>` element inside `<td>` but I wonder to get a solution with CSS. I also don't manage to apply `vertical-align:middle;` at the input.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Wernfried/3ph32L7a/8/

Page is created dynamically, using jQuery `$("#id").width()` would be an option, if required.

Comment: Do you use bootstrap 3/4?

Comment: No, I don't use bootstrap

Comment: you don't want to use bootstrap?

Comment: I think bootstrap would be an overkill just for a single element - then I would go for an inline table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even change the default `display` of `span to inline-block`, this makes difference and align `input` and `span` tag separately as below,

```css
body { 
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#765452;
 margin:0px; 
 font-size:16px; 
}

fieldset { margin:0.4em 0.5em; }
fieldset legend { font-weight: bold; }
fieldset table { width:auto; border-collapse:collapse; }
fieldset table td { padding:0.4em 0.75em 0.4em 0.5em; border:1px solid ActiveBorder; }
fieldset table th { padding:0.2em 1em; border-style:solid; border-color:ActiveBorder; border-width:1px 1px 2px; } 
#id{
  margin-top:5px;
}
.calloutTitle {
  width:60%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset><legend>Callout Report</legend>
<table>
<tr><td>Start Time</td><td>
<input type="text" id="startTimeUI" autocomplete="off" />
</td></tr>

<tr><td>Callout&nbsp;ID</td><td>
<input type="text" id="id" name="id" size="10" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" />
<span class="calloutTitle">This can be a longer text which takes more than just one single line.</span>
</td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

**Update -**

Same using `display inline-block` to align `span` text separately and even change the default `vertical-align` of `td` tag.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #765452;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0.4em 0.5em;
}

fieldset legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}

fieldset table {
  width: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

fieldset table td {
  padding: 0.4em 0.75em 0.4em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid ActiveBorder;
}

fieldset table th {
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: ActiveBorder;
  border-width: 1px 1px 2px;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(2) td{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(2) td > input{
  width:150px;
}
table tr:nth-of-type(2) td > span{
  width:calc(90% - 150px);
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Callout Report</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Start Time</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="startTimeUI" autocomplete="off" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Callout&nbsp;ID</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="id" name="id" size="10" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" />
        <span class="calloutTitle">This can be a longer text which takes more than just one single line.</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I think `#id{  margin-top:5px;}` is a cheat. What happens if the text is even longer (e.g. 3 lines). Also it fails for short calloutTitle.

Comment: To align input properly I used margin-top in above codes, check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t6f0rwyc/ same using display:inline-block. If you want all fields to be vertically center even when span text range increase then your table idea is right.

Comment: Solution of https://jsfiddle.net/t6f0rwyc/1/ works. best. If you put it in your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Use css `flex` property

```css
body { 
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#765452;
  margin:0px; 
  font-size:16px; 
}
fieldset {
  margin: 0.4em 0.5em;
}
fieldset legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}
fieldset table {
  width: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
fieldset table td {
  padding: 0.4em 0.75em 0.4em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid ActiveBorder;
}
fieldset table th {
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: ActiveBorder;
  border-width: 1px 1px 2px;
}
.calloutTitle {
  margin-left:10px;
}
.custom-class{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Callout Report</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Start Time</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="startTimeUI" autocomplete="off" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Callout&nbsp;ID</td>
      <td class="custom-class">
        <input type="text" id="id" name="id" size="10" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" />
        <span class="calloutTitle">This can be a longer text which takes more than just one single line.</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Seems to work but some border-lines are double. I added `border-width: 0px; border-right-width:1px;` (and `border-bottom-width:1px;` in case of last row) to make it better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #765452;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
fieldset {
  margin: 0.4em 0.5em;
}
fieldset legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}
fieldset table {
  width: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
fieldset table td {
  padding: 0.4em 0.75em 0.4em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid ActiveBorder;
}
fieldset table th {
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: ActiveBorder;
  border-width: 1px 1px 2px;
}
.call-out {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.calloutTitle {
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Callout Report</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Start Time</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="startTimeUI" autocomplete="off" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="callout">Callout&nbsp;ID</td>
      <td class="call-out">
        <input type="text" id="id" name="id" size="10" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" />
        <span class="calloutTitle">This can be a longer text which takes more than just one single line.</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

We just need to add the below CSS to get it working without changing the existing code. just use the flex and get the results in the same way.

```
`fieldset table td {
    padding: 0.4em 0.75em 0.4em 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid ActiveBorder;
    display: flex;
}`
```

Comment: This also changes the height of `<input>`

Comment: display: flex; align-items: center;    hope it works

Comment: Yes, now it is the same like answer from bruce182